# Pairing to Bluetooth device automatically with External Accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, connection, external-accessory

I am using EASession (External Accessory) library to integrate with my **Non**-BLE Bluetooth device. I am looking for a way to pair my device automatically without the need to go to the: iPhone Settings->Bluetooth->select my device->and manually click on the device.
is there a way I can get the list of all Bluetooth devices which already paired and send a connection command? 
Objective-C answer will be appreciated

Comment: You can display the pairing dialogue within your app. Is your peripheral MFi certified?

Comment: Yes , my peripheral is MFi certified. is there any way to do this operation automatically?

Comment: No, as far as I know, the user must still select the accessory to pair https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager/1613913-showbluetoothaccessorypicker. Allowing an app to pair a peripheral without user intervention is a potential security and privacy risk.